# Fill color with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes, scoping

This code produce Fig. 2. Is there a way to get Fig. 1?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.5]
  \begin{scope}
    \shade[left color=yellow, bottom color=orange, right color=red]% fill opacity=0.5]
      (-0.5,5.5) -- (8.5,3) -- (8.5,6.5) -- (-0.5,6.5) -- cycle;
   %   \shade[left color=yellow, right color=white, fill opacity=0.5]
     % (2.5,6.5) -- (8.5,6.5) -- (8.5,3) -- (5,3) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `scope` you can draw a `\shade` as a rectangle and then use `\clip` to cut out any form you like. Since I don't know the exact form I just used a line with `bend`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.5]
  \begin{scope}
    \clip[draw] (0.5,3) to[bend left=20] (8.5,6) -- (8.5,3) to[bend right=30] (0.5,1) -- cycle; 
    \shade[left color=yellow, bottom color=orange, right color=red](0,0) rectangle (9,7);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As stated by esdd in the comment, the same figure can be done with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.5]
  \shade[draw,left color=yellow,right color=red]  (0.5,3) to[bend left=20] (8.5,6) -- (8.5,3) to[bend right=30] (0.5,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I think that there is no clipping needed. `\draw[shade,left color=yellow,right color=red] (0.5,3) to[bend left=20] (8.5,6) -- (8.5,3) to[bend right=30] (0.5,1) -- cycle;` should do the same. Note that `bottom color` can be removed because its followed and therefore overwritten by `right color`.

Comment: @esdd I come to think of that also after posting it. It is easier without clipping, but could be more general with. Maybe. I have added it to the answer.